# How to see lowered c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to improve my understanding of how C++ actually works.  Is there a way to see how the compiler lowers my code into something simpler?  For example, I'd like to see how all the copy constructors are called, how overloaded function calls have been resolved, all the template expansion and instantiation complete, etc.  Right now I'm learning about how C++ compilers interpret my code through experimentation, but it'd be nice just to see a lowered form of my code, even if it is very ugly.  I'm looking for something analogous to g++ -E, which shows the result of the preprocessor, but for C++.

Edit: I should have added that I'm not looking for a disassembler.  There's a huge gulf between C++ source code and assembled code.  Inside this gulf are complicated things like template meta-programming and all sorts of implicit calls to operator methods (assignments! casts! constructors! ...) as well as heavily overloaded functions with very complicated resolution rules, etc.  I'm looking for tools to help me understand how my code is interpreted by the C++ compiler.  Right now, the only thing I can do is try little experiments and piecemeal put together an understanding of what the compiler is doing.  I'd like to see more detail on what's going on.  It would help greatly, for example, in debugging template metaprogramming problems.

Comment: It's not exactly what you're looking for, but I think will be of interest: Stan Lippman's book, "Inside the C++ Object Model" explains how various C++ constructs could be implemented.  So it won't tell you what *your* compiler is doing, or exactly what's going on with *your* code, but it explains the general concepts behind how C++ features might work.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to see compiled code (`gcc -S`) or something else?

Comment: I was hoping for something higher level than gcc -S.

Answer (score 7):

At the moment, I think that your best bet is *Clang* (you can try some simple code on the [Try Out LLVM](http://llvm.org/demo/index.cgi) page).

When compiling C, C++ or Obj-C with Clang/LLVM, you may ask the compiler to emit the Intermediate Representation (LLVM IR) instead of going the full way to assembly/binary form.

The LLVM IR is a full specified language used internally by the compiler:

- CLang lowers the C++ code to LLVM IR
- LLVM optimizes the IR
- A LLVM Backend (for example x86) produces the assembly from the IR

The IR is the last step before machine-specific code, so you don't have to learn specific assembly directives and you still get a very low-level representation of what's really going on under the hood.

You can get the IR both before and after optimizations, the latter being more representative of real code, but further away from what you origially wrote.

Example with a C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int factorial(int X) {
  if (X == 0) return 1;
  return X*factorial(X-1);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  printf("%d\n", factorial(atoi(argv[1])));
}
```

Corresponding IR:

```
; ModuleID = '/tmp/webcompile/_10956_0.bc'
target datalayout = "e-p:64:64:64-i1:8:8-i8:8:8-i16:16:16-i32:32:32-i64:64:64-f32:32:32-f64:64:64-v64:64:64-v128:128:128-a0:0:64-s0:64:64-f80:128:128-n8:16:32:64"
target triple = "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"

@.str = private unnamed_addr constant [4 x i8] c"%d\0A\00"

define i32 @main(i32 %argc, i8** nocapture %argv) nounwind {
; <label>:0
  %1 = getelementptr inbounds i8** %argv, i64 1
  %2 = load i8** %1, align 8, !tbaa !0
  %3 = tail call i64 @strtol(i8* nocapture %2, i8** null, i32 10) nounwind
  %4 = trunc i64 %3 to i32
  %5 = icmp eq i32 %4, 0
  br i1 %5, label %factorial.exit, label %tailrecurse.i

tailrecurse.i:                                    ; preds = %tailrecurse.i, %0
  %indvar.i = phi i32 [ %indvar.next.i, %tailrecurse.i ], [ 0, %0 ]
  %accumulator.tr1.i = phi i32 [ %6, %tailrecurse.i ], [ 1, %0 ]
  %X.tr2.i = sub i32 %4, %indvar.i
  %6 = mul nsw i32 %X.tr2.i, %accumulator.tr1.i
  %indvar.next.i = add i32 %indvar.i, 1
  %exitcond = icmp eq i32 %indvar.next.i, %4
  br i1 %exitcond, label %factorial.exit, label %tailrecurse.i

factorial.exit:                                   ; preds = %tailrecurse.i, %0
  %accumulator.tr.lcssa.i = phi i32 [ 1, %0 ], [ %6, %tailrecurse.i ]
  %7 = tail call i32 (i8*, ...)* @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([4 x i8]* @.str, i64 0, i64 0), i32 %accumulator.tr.lcssa.i) nounwind
  ret i32 0
}

declare i32 @printf(i8* nocapture, ...) nounwind

declare i64 @strtol(i8*, i8** nocapture, i32) nounwind

!0 = metadata !{metadata !"any pointer", metadata !1}
!1 = metadata !{metadata !"omnipotent char", metadata !2}
!2 = metadata !{metadata !"Simple C/C++ TBAA", null}
```

I personally find it relatively readable (it tries to preserve the variable names, somewhat, the function names are still there) once you get past the original discovery of the language.

Comment: I've never been able to get llvm to work to compile anything. Everybody talks about it, and Fedora 15 has packages for it, but there doesn't seem to be any obvious way to run the compiler or anything.

Comment: Omnifarious: have you tried reading the [great documentation](http://llvm.org/docs/#userguide)? And Clang's [equally great documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html)?

Comment: @rubenvb - Yes, I have looked through it, and I've still never been able to get it to work. I just want to fire off a command, giving it a .cpp file as an argument and get an executable back. All that documentation seems to assume that I want to do something more fancy. And maybe someday I'll care about that, but I until I can produce executables I don't.

Comment: Omnifarious: and `clang++ file.cpp -o program` doesn't work for you?

Comment: @rubenvb: It will now. I never even knew what packages needed to be installed. I installed all the llvm related ones and none of them ever contained anything recognizable as a compiler. `yum install /usr/bin/clang++` and there we go.

Comment: Omnifarious: either llvm-gcc (which mimicks gcc 4.2) or clang is what you needed all along :)

Comment: @Omnifarious: I understand from where you come from, much of the talk today is about the LLVM Compiler, but the truth is that LLVM is an umbrella project and the compiler really is CLang. And this is not helped by the fact that Apple rebrands everything (comprising version numbers) when delivering XCode :/ I'll update my first sentence to make it clearer.

Answer (score 3):

The first C++ compiler was `cfront`, which was, as the name implies, a front-end for `C`; in theory, `cfront`'s output is what you'd like to see. But `cfront` hasn't been available for many years; it was a commercial product, and the source is not available.

Modern C++ compilers don't use a C intermediary; if there's an intermediary at all, it's an internal compiler representation, not something you'd enjoy looking at! The `-S` option to g++ will spit out `*.s` files: assembly code, which includes just enough symbols that you could, in theory, follow it.

Answer (score 2):

The very first (circa 1989) C++ compilers compiled C++ into C. But that's not been true for a very long time, very long time meaning I know of no widely available compiler than did things that way for the last 15 years. The best you are going to do is look at the assembly language output, which requires some amount of knowledge and analysis to understand.

The assembly level output of a C++ compiler is generally not called 'lowered'. It's called 'compiled'. I can understand how you might come by that terminology. Assembly is a lower-level language. But that's not the terminology everybody else uses and it will confuse people if you use it.

Most popular C++ compilers have an option somewhere that allows you to see the assembly level output. The Open Source `g++` compiler has the `-S` option that does this. It will create a file that ends in `.s`. You can look through this file to see the resulting assembly language.

In order for the assembly language to more directly correspond to the C++ code I would recommend compiling with the `-O0` option to turn off optimization. The results of optimization can result in assembly code that bears little or no obvious resemblance to the original C++ code. Though viewing that code can help you understand what the optimizer is doing.

Another problem is that the symbols (the names for functions and classes and things) in the assembly output will be what is called 'mangled'. This is because most assembly languages do not allow `::` as part of the symbol name, and because C++ can also have the same names for different kinds of symbols. The compiler transforms the names of things in your C++ code into different names that will be valid in the assembly code.

For `g++` this mangling can be undone with the `c++filt` program.

```
c++filt <myprogram.s >myprogram_demangled.s
```

This will help make the assembly file more readable.

Answer (score 1):

- First step you can **preprocess** it (It is the first step that the compiler actually do before compiling)

> with [cpp](http://cf.ccmr.cornell.edu/cgi-bin/w3mman2html.cgi?cpp%281%29) or `g++ -E`

- Second step is to **parse and translate** it

> with g++ -S

this [link](http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/sigmil/RevEng/ch02.html) about the compilation process might interest you

Answer (score 0):

You can run g++ (or any gcc front-end) with one or more of the `-fdump-tree-` flags ([complete list](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html)), which will dump intermediate representations of the code from different compiler passes in an output format that looks similar to C. However, this output is usually quite hard to read, with lots of compiler-generated temporary variables and other artifacts of compilation. It's mainly intended for debugging the compiler itself, but for simple examples you might be able to infer what gcc is doing with your C++ code by studying the intermediate representation.

Answer (score 0):

The [Comeau C++ compiler](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/) generates C code. But you'll have to pay for it.

Comment: And is generally doesn't show the C code (it's in temporary files that are quickly erased), so you won't get much help from it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing experimentation, you can use a debugger and see the flow of your code. This way you can easily see which constructors or overloaded functions actual mapping is happening.

Comment: This is helpful for many problems, but not template metaprogramming bugs - since they preclude creating a binary to run in a debugger.